# Who is the man at the ending of "Extraterrestrial"?

Tags: plot-explanation, extraterrestrial

In the end of the movie [**Extraterrestrial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_(2014_film)) we see a covert military operation, cleaning up the mess of the aliens. We see a man who seems to be in command of this operation.

The way the scene is filmed (showing him blurred from behind, than moving around him slowly revealing his face)  indicates that I should recognize him and should be surprised by this revelation. But I totally missed the point who he is.

- Should I know him from another scene in the movie where he pretends to be someone else?

Or is it an joke or homage about the actor who played a similar role in another movie (he strongly reminds me to the smoker in x-files)?

I read somewhere, that the whole ending scene is replicating the ending of another movie. If so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One review](https://thedissolve.com/reviews/1223-extraterrestrial/) states:

> While the sap is counteracted to some degree by a deeply cynical
>   ending, said ending is itself compromised by having been baldly
>   swiped, with only minor (and even more cynical) modifications, from
>   the jarring conclusion of one of the most famous horror movies ever
>   made. Playing around with archetypes is one thing; replicating one of
>   cinema’s most indelible moments is another.

Another review, which I can't seem to link to, mentions:

> The film caps off with a very X-Files routine. Cliché characters, one
>   of whom seems to have been awkwardly transplanted from an '80s teen
>   horror film, and all of whom play out cliché melodrama during very
>   obvious and convenient breaks in action, didn't really help things.

According to reviews on Amazon, the ending was, in fact, a tip of the hat to The Smoking Man from The X-Files.